# sorting month in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server

*I have looked at related Qs on Stack*.
I am trying to sort my query to display month in ascending order. A similar post on Stack said that I must indicate "ASC", but this doesn't work for me. I have written an Order By. I cannot figure out why it is not working.

```
SELECT  DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) AS [Date]        
FROM Submission 
GROUP BY DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

This is the output:

```
  Month
  August
 February
 September
```

Note: this is just a part of my query, I didnt think it would necessary to show the rest, which relates to other attributes from my table (Not month related)

Edit: This is my Entire Query: (The Initial One)

```
SELECT  DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) AS [Date], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Under review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Under_Review], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Accepted], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Rejected], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='In print' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [In_print], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Published] 
FROM Submission INNER JOIN ((Faculty INNER JOIN School ON Faculty.FacultyID = School.[FacultyID]) INNER JOIN (Researcher INNER JOIN ResearcherSubmission ON Researcher.ResearcherID = ResearcherSubmission.ResearcherID) ON School.SchoolID = Researcher.SchoolID) ON Submission.SubmissionID = ResearcherSubmission.SubmissionID 
GROUP BY DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) 
ORDER BY DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate));
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Some product specific SQL in your statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to add `MONTH(Submission.SubmissionDate)` to your `group by` clause, and `order by` that as well:

```
SELECT  DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) AS [Date]        
FROM Submission 
GROUP BY MONTH(Submission.SubmissionDate), DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate))
ORDER BY MONTH(Submission.SubmissionDate)
```

This will work for your real query as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  DATENAME( MONTH, Submission.SubmissionDate) AS [Date]        
FROM Submission 
ORDER BY datepart(mm,Submission.SubmissionDate)
```

You don't need a `group by` (for the query shown). Also, when you `order by` `month name` it would return results in the alphabetical order of `month name`. You should not use previously defined `alias`es in the `where`,`order by` `having` and `group by` clauses.

Edit: The problem is with the `join` conditions. You should correct them as per the comments in line.

```
SELECT DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) AS [Date], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Under review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Under_Review], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Accepted], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Rejected], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='In print' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [In_print], 
SUM( CASE WHEN Submission.Status='Published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Published] 
FROM Faculty 
INNER JOIN School ON Faculty.FacultyID = School.[FacultyID]
INNER JOIN Researcher ON School.SchoolID = Researcher.SchoolID
INNER JOIN ResearcherSubmission ON Researcher.ResearcherID = ResearcherSubmission.ResearcherID 
INNER JOIN SUBMISSION ON Submission.SubmissionID = ResearcherSubmission.SubmissionID 
GROUP BY DATENAME( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) 
ORDER BY DATEPART( MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate))
```

Comment: Why do you say he doesn't need the `group by`?

Comment: the query shown wasn't using any aggregate functions.

Comment: He could be using it to eliminate duplicate rows though.

Comment: yes..maybe he will need it in the full query he is using. but to be appropriate i only corrected what was shown.

Comment: thanks the Order By method works for me. However, as people have commented above, the purpose of my Group By is to eliminate duplicates. When I use the Group By however, it causes errors

Comment: you should post the full query then

Comment: see the edited answer. the problem is with the `join` conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate)) AS [Date]        
FROM Submission 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,(Submission.SubmissionDate))
ORDER BY MIN([Date]) ASC;
```

This chooses an arbitrary date from each group and orders by that.

By the way, you probably should care about the year as well as the month.  If so:

```
SELECT YEAR(s.SubmissionDate), DATENAME(MONTH, s.SubmissionDate) AS [Date]        
FROM Submission s
GROUP BY YEAR(s.SubmissionDate), DATENAME(MONTH, s.SubmissionDate)
ORDER BY MIN([Date]) ASC;
```